# Can't access some websites with Squid Proxy

Tags: proxy

I wanna connect to banned websites (p*rnhub and wikipedia is disabled on Turkey) so I installed Squid Proxy succesfully on my VPS server.

Everything is OK, Proxy is working and i can surf at internet but i can't access to banned websites still.

I take "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error. My VPS is locating on Germany.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your ISP/government is smart enough to also intercept proxy server connections and reset them when connection to banned destination is detected.

You likely need secured (VPN, IPsec, TLS) connection between yourself and your VPS.

The other possiblity is blocking on DNS resolution level. You may also consider running your own resolver on the VPS.

Comment: Thx so much! I will search your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try chrome extension [DotVPN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dotvpn-%E2%80%94-a-better-way-to/kpiecbcckbofpmkkkdibbllpinceiihk?hl=en).

Comment: I want to setup my own Proxy Server